# Does Nitrous.io allow port 80?

Tags: nitrousio

Is it possible to start my webserver/webrick/node.js at standard port 80 on Nitrous.io? A lot of company policies don't allow browsing of non-standard port website.

Can I have root access to my virtual machine?

Comment: Sorry, it is not my idea of using Stackoverflow to post this question, but http://help.nitrous.io/discussions/

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow for discussion of the practice of redirecting product support to SO

Comment: help.nitrous.io/discussions has been updated to better clarify the intensions of when to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

Nitrous.IO currently has ports 1024 - 9999 open only for HTTP. Root access is not available at this time.

You can then access your site via that particular port, or directly on the usual http (port 80) and https ports (port 443).

**Custom domain support will be available soon for paying users.**

Comment: So how do we make it so that users go to www.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com:3000?

Comment: Nitrous.io is mainly for developing. not intended for production

Answer (score 2):

We recently shipped an update that will forward port 80 to port 3000.  So you can run your web server on port 3000 and you will still be able to preview your application even if you are behind a company firewall.